# How to shrink an encrypted BTRFS partition?

Tags: arch-linux, partition, parted

I have an external USB HDD (WD Elements). The entire drive is currently one large partition. Call it /dev/sda1. This partition was encrypted like this:

```
cryptsetup -v --type luks --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --hash sha512 --key-size 512 --use-random luksFormat /dev/sda1 --key-file /path/to/key
```

Then I created the BTRFS filesystem in it. (Note: I'm not using LVM.)

Now I have a need to reduce the size of that partition and create an NTFS partition on the USB HDD. (I'm actually doing this for a friend.)

I came across this article [Resize an Encrypted Partition without Breaking your Linux System | by Timothy D Beach | Medium](https://thequantitative.medium.com/resize-an-encrypted-partition-without-breaking-your-linux-system-6ef475619745)

That articles doesn't give me full confidence, so before starting I want to ask about potential pitfalls. What steps should I use to resize the partition and give me space for an NTFS partition?

I believe the NTFS partition cannot be encrypted if I want to share it between Windows and Linux, right?

**EDIT:** So far I completed this step:

```
mount /mnt/btrfsvolume
btrfs fi resize 1:-500G /mnt/btrfsvolume
```

**EDIT 2:**

Then I did these steps:

```
parted /dev/sda
(parted) print
  NOTE: shows end at 5001GB
(parted) resizepart 1 4505
(parted) print
(parted) quit
```

That should have given me 4 GB "margin of safety" because I reduced the filesystem by 500G and I reduced the partition by only 496G.

Everything seemed OK afterwards. The device could be decrypted and mounted, and I could read files on it. But I started getting strange system errors. For examples, if the drive is mounted, "pacman -Syu" fails with errors that are not logical. If I unmount the drive, I don't get any errors. (The errors are a long story, probably not worth adding to this thread because the problem is clearly the result of resizing the partition on the external device, not anything wrong with my system.)

Comment: As you mention /dev/sda1, I assume you have a partition table there. I believe the answer will be along the lines of first resizing the btrfs volume, then the luks volume, then the actual disk partition. If you're able to reduce all 3 "layers" you should get unused disk space to create a new partition (say /dev/sda2), which you should format as ntfs and see if Windows (or perhaps veracrypt) will be able to encrypt it. If I get the time I might write a proper answer, but I hope this can already help you somehow.

Comment: @Zip do you know how to resize the luks parition? I can probably figure out the other 2 layers.

Comment: I believe you can find the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460374/maximally-shrink-lvm-pv-and-luks-container-partition

Comment: @Zip I'm not using LVM, as I said in my question.

Comment: Have you scrubbed and btrfs check'ed (without repair) the btrfs filesystem?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa - yes, I ran `btrfs check --check-data-csum` and it reported no errors. I also ran it without any options.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa scrub does report errors: `Error summary:    read=15350673 super=1
  Corrected:      0
  Uncorrectable:  15350673
  Unverified:     0`

Comment: This was interesting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239765/how-to-fix-btrfs-superblock-error-after-resize-shrink-btrfs-couldnt-get-super . However, it failed for me. I gave up and reformatted the disk.